# Как реализовать перемещение окна держась за Canvas в tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, bind, motion

Как реализовать перемещение окна держась за Canvas в tkinter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Набросок, пока далекий от идеала. Перемещение окна происходит в момент отпускания мыши. При таком варианте работает корректно (после отпускания окно будет смещено так, что указатель мыши будет указывать на то же место окна, как и при нажатии мышью).</s>

Если расскомментировать строку `canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', update_position)`, окно будет перемещаться при перемещении мыши с зажатой левой кнопкой, но движение неравномерное, с непонятными скачками вправо-влево, вверх-вниз. Пока не удалось разобраться в причинах такого поведения.

Исправил. Суть алгоритма такая: при нажатии мышью на окно берем координаты окна и координаты курсора (абсолютные), рассчитываем разницу (`dif`), запоминаем ее. При перемещении мыши берем координаты мыши (опять же, абсолютные), прибавляем  разницу `dif`, получаем необходимые координаты окна.

[image: Схема]

До этого как-то пытался реализовать через координаты курсора относительно `canvas`, сейчас прикинул на векторах, и не понял, как это должно было работать)

Ниже исправленная реализация:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def on_mouse_down(event):
    global dif_x, dif_y
    win_position = [int(coord) for coord in root.wm_geometry().split('+')[1:]]
    dif_x, dif_y = win_position[0] - event.x_root, win_position[1] - event.y_root


def update_position(event):
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (event.x_root + dif_x, event.y_root + dif_y))


canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_mouse_down)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', update_position)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Неплохо, а может попробовать через "<Motion>" как-то сделать?

Comment: @оаавирыыва по идее различия не должно быть с b1-motion, только ещё придётся проверять, что кнопка мыши нажата. Но в любом случае вечером попробую.

Comment: рисунок неточный. `root.winfo_y()` это точка ниже угла (на размер системного заголовка окна). Она указывает на угол содержимого, а не самого окна. Запустив ваш код: в самом начале движения прыжок происходит на высоту декорации окна (я не просто так в своём ответе регулярные выражения использую, чтобы `rect['y']` значение для geometry() получить). У вас на Windows нет прыжка?

Comment: @jfs, нет, у меня никаких прыжков не заметно. Минут через 15, когда lubuntu на виртуалку поставится проверю и там.

Comment: @insolor прыжок маленький ~25 пикселей. Сравните значения y, возвращаемые geometry() и winfo_y().

Comment: @jfs, `print(root.wm_geometry(), root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y())` дает `382x269+649+257 649 257`

Comment: @jfs, действительно, под linux скачок на высоту заголовка. Откатил ответ до предыдущей редакции до "улучшения".

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы таскать главное окно, держась за canvas:

1. Запомнить начальные координаты при нажатии мышки
2. Двигать главное окно вслед за мышкой, пока кнопка нажата

Сложная часть оказалась в том, чтобы учесть высоту ширину системных декораций вокруг корневого окна (чтобы мышка не прыгала при начале движения):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import tkinter as tk


class DraggableByCanvasWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.geometry("200x200")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.bind('<1>', self.on_mouse_press)  # pressed over the widget
        # mouse is move while being held down
        canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_drag)

    def on_mouse_press(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

    def on_drag(self, event):
        rect = re.fullmatch(r'\d+x\d+\+(?P<x>-?\d+)\+(?P<y>-?\d+)',
                            self.geometry()).groupdict()
        # NOTE: self.winfo_root*() is content's coordinate without window decorations
        x = int(rect['x']) + (event.x - self.start_x)
        y = int(rect['y']) + (event.y - self.start_y)
        self.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DraggableByCanvasWindow().mainloop()
```

[image: screencast drag tkinter window by canvas]

Comment: Как ты делаешь такие gif?

Comment: @оаавирыыва: byzanz-record

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать c `B1-Motion` (но как по мне кажется это не совсем то что нужно)

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("200x200")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', 
                         lambda e: self.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.winfo_pointerx(), self.winfo_pointery())))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `<Motion>` подходит, но мышка прыгает в левый-верхний угол здесь. Оказалось, что немного усложнёно это исправить.

Answer (score 0):

```
def b1motion(root,e):
    root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (root.winfo_x()+e.x-root.start.x, root.winfo_y()+e.y-root.start.y))
def motion(root,e):
    root.start=e
elem.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e:b1motion(root,e))
elem.bind('<Motion>',    lambda e:  motion(root,e))
```

Вместо root надо подставить переменную вашего окна, а вместо elem любой виджет.

Comment: Работает, но при начале перетаскивание окно смещается, как тут в комментарии описано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807953/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0-canvas-%D0%B2-tkinter#comment1281777_808550