# Магнитное окно на tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как реализовать магнитное окно, как например окна [steam](https://store.steampowered.com/), которые магнитятся к краям экрана?

cfg root: `root.resizable(width=False, height=False)`

Comment: обычно за это ваш менеджер окон (окружение рабочего стола) отвечает: любые окна, а не только окна какого-то конкретного приложения прилипают к краям экрана.

Comment: Я не понял что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Я имею в виду, если окно не может менять диагональ: `root.resizable(width=False, height=False)`

Comment: пример как окна к краям экрана прилипают https://youtu.be/2qKKHaYy6WE

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего не идеал, но хоть что то с тем учетом что вы будете пользоваться `Canvas` из [предыдущего вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807953/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0-canvas-%D0%B2-tkinter), а так по сути [@jfs уже сказал вам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823738/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-tkinter-python/823785#comment1312242_823738), если вы уберете `resizable(width=False, height=False)` то менеджер окон будет сам может "прилипать" окна к краям экрана, а с этой функцией( `resizable(width=False, height=False)`) у вас окно становится статическим по этому менеджер окон не делает так

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_mouse_down)
        canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda e: self.config())
        canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.update_position)

    def config(self):
        cursor_w, cursor_y = self.winfo_pointerx(), self.winfo_pointery()
        if 0 <= cursor_w <= self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - 400 and 0 <= cursor_y <= self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 50:
            self.position_root(0, 0)

        elif 0 <= cursor_w <= self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - 400 and self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 + 50 <= cursor_y <= self.winfo_screenheight():
            self.position_root(0, self.winfo_screenheight() - self.winfo_height() - 70)

        elif self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 + 400 <= cursor_w <= self.winfo_screenwidth() and 0 <= cursor_y <= self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 50:
            self.position_root(self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.winfo_width(), 0)

        elif self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 + 400 <= cursor_w <= self.winfo_screenwidth() and self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 + 50 <= cursor_y <= self.winfo_screenheight():
            self.position_root(self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_screenheight() - self.winfo_height() - 70)

    def on_mouse_down(self, event):
        self.win_position = [int(coord) for coord in self.wm_geometry().split('+')[1:]]
        self.dif_x, self.dif_y = self.win_position[0] - event.x_root, self.win_position[1] - event.y_root

    def update_position(self, event):
        self.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (event.x_root + self.dif_x, event.y_root + self.dif_y))

    def position_root(self, x, y):
        self.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно пока сделать без `Canvas`, и чтоб магнитился не только по краям, но и по сторонам?