# Как нажатием кнопки Tkinter менять значения других виджетов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, значение 'relx'переменной 'snake' увеличивалось на 0.1
Как это можно реализовать?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def move():
    snake['relx']+=0.1
snake = Canvas(root, bg='green', width=20,height=20).place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1)
Button(root, bg='Black', command=move).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я знаю, что код, который я скинул не будет работать. Я скинул его для более лучшего понимания моей проблемы

Comment: Если вы хотите двигать по окну само полотно!, то почитайте здесь <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807953/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0-canvas-%D0%B2-tkinter>. Но чаще создаются объекты на холсте и их анимируют, про это здесь <https://younglinux.info/tkinter/canvasmeth>.